# Connect to openvpn past enterprise firewall

Tags: firewall, openvpn

I have a dd-wrt router at home running openvpn, I am able to connect to it from 
any other location except from my office.

Firewall at office :

port 80 , 443 is open (I can access any website anywhere)
ping and everything else is blocked.

I tried to run openvpn in tcp mode @ port 443, still connection is refused.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way is to do this :

1. Setup openvpn to use tcp instead of udp on any port (1194 is default)
2. Setup port forwarding to forward external 443 port to internal 1194 port.
3. If the web browser on client side is using a proxy setup the openvpn client to use the proxy server for connection.
4. Setup client to use tcp and port 443 .

Then connect.